# how to fix pyaudio installation problem windows 11

Tags: python

C:\Users\HP\Downloads>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: 'MS_WIN64' previously declared on the command line
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

Comment: A search on "pyaudio windows" turns up dozens of hits, many of which seem relevant. How is your problem different?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.